# VLC core video players?

Tags: media-player, vlc-media-player

I'm looking for a media player that uses the VLC core technology. VLC can handle all my media files greatly, however I'm looking for an alternative media player that uses VLC code and has a better "library" sense. Kantaris is an example of that, however there application is buggy and slow. Any suggestions? Windows and Free please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard great things about [Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/). I've never used it, but it looks good and seems to have a decent library feature.

There's also [a list of projects using VLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/We_Use_VideoLAN) on their official Wiki. You could look for media players in there.

[Songbird](http://getsongbird.com/) used to use the VLC core, but switched to [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) (which is similar) a while ago.